# What is causing all these DNS queries?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

I've switched to Amazon's Route 53 service for three small, low-traffic domains last month.  The first bill just came in, and it was something a shock.

The number of queries for the first month for the three domains was 17 million, 25 million, and 75 million, respectively.  That last is just used for a (very) small corporate website and email.  It gets less than 200 visitors a month, and maybe a few dozen email messages (mostly spam).  How in the world did it generate 75 ***million*** DNS queries?  That's like...30 queries per second?!

That's not normal volume, is it?

Is there any way I can figure this out?  Does anyone know if Amazon offers any reporting that could help me figure out this query volume?

Comment: Clearly either Amazon's billing is in error or someone is specifically trying to run up Amazon Route 53 bills.

Comment: Our medium-traffic domains average 30 queries per *minute* (total on all authoritative name servers). You're seeing more than 50 times that.

Comment: While the cost is a problem in itself, I would worry that there is a sloppily written script trying to guess your passwords or sending spam thru a mailserver in the domain. tcpdump/wireshark on the boxen named by those DNS records would be my first action.

Comment: What is your DNS TTL value? Is it too small?

Comment: @Khaled It's 300, which seems to be the default on Route 53.  That may be making the issue worse and I'll try increasing it...but honestly, I can't see that being the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely shouldn't be seeing that many queries if you hosted your own NS. It's possible that there's a spammer hijacking your domain. You'd likely see a large number of PTR queries if it was sending mail, if you're able to check.

However because it's hosted on Amazon AWS IP space there's inherently more scanning/querying on this provider than if you hosted your domain on your own IP space.

Try and get a report from them based on the top querying IPs and their country origins. I wouldn't be surprised if it was due to some Chinese botnets scanning that Amazon doesn't filter out befor billing.